# VBA code for sorting data not working only on data uploaded to Excel by Power Query

Tags: vba, sorting, filtering, powerquery

Why the below code isn't working on data uploaded to Excel by PowerQuery while it is working totally fine on the same data that was exported from the system to excel file?

```
Sheet1.Activate
If Not Sheet1.AutoFilterMode Then Sheet1.UsedRange.AutoFilter
If Sheet1.Cells.AutoFilter Then Sheet1.Cells.AutoFilter

    With ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=dataRows.Columns(1) 'sort by Number
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=dataRows.Columns(2) 'sort by Region
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=dataRows.Columns(4) 'sort by Date
        .Apply
    End With
```

This is how my data is sorted when running macro on data exported from the system to Excel file.
And that is what I want.
And the most important part is that the Created Date is sorted correctly - from oldest to newest for each particular Number and Region.

```
Number  Region  Created Date
4350257 EMEA    16/08/2018
4350257 EMEA    03/03/2020
4350257 NA      14/12/2018
4350257 NA      20/12/2018
4879668 EMEA    05/11/2018
4879668 EMEA    14/11/2018
```

This is when running the same Macro, but with data that has been uploaded by PowerQuery:
QUESTION: Why the Created Date is not sorted properly? (from oldest to newest)

```
Number  Region  Created Date
4350257 EMEA    03/03/2020
4350257 EMEA    16/08/2018
4879668 EMEA    03/03/2020
4879668 EMEA    26/02/2020
4350257 NA      14/12/2018
4350257 NA      20/12/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the format of Created Date column from General to Date. And it is working.
I hadn't noticed that before.